# PHP FPM Docker ZF1: The session has already been started. The session id must be set first

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, docker, docker-compose

In my dev environment, I'm trying to replace the old heavy Vagrant VM with Docker, using `docker-compose`:

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        build: ./containers/nginx
        networks:
            mm:
                ipv4_address: 172.25.0.101
        environment:
            APPLICATION_ENV: development
        extra_hosts:
            - "mysite.dev:127.0.0.1"
        ports:
            - 80:80
        links:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ../:/srv

    php:
        build: ./containers/php-fpm
        networks:
            mm:
                ipv4_address: 172.25.0.102
        volumes:
            - ../:/srv
        links:
            - memcached
        ports:
            - 9000:9000

    memcached:
        image: memcached:latest
        ports:
            - 1234:11211
        networks:
            mm:
                ipv4_address: 172.25.0.103

networks:
    mm:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.25.0.0/24
```

But the application is written with ZF1, and whenever I instantiate an `Zend_Session_Namespace` object just after `Zend_Session::start()` the following error appears:

```
Zend_Session_Exception: The session has already been started. The session id must be set first. in /srv/mm/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Session.php on line 667
```

I've tried it all, mouting a session path with `VOLUME`, changing the `session.save_path`, installing it all again and again, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spent a long debugging this issue I've found the answer for your question. On the second time you call `Zend_Session::start()` ZF will validate the session id by checking whether it was generated with proper `hash_bits_per_character` defined by php_ini setting `session.hash_bits_per_character` or not.

```
/**
 * From Zend_Session 
 */
protected static function _checkId($id)
{
    $saveHandler = ini_get('session.save_handler');
    if ($saveHandler == 'cluster') { // Zend Server SC, validate only after last dash
        $dashPos = strrpos($id, '-');
        if ($dashPos) {
            $id = substr($id, $dashPos + 1);
        }
    }

    $hashBitsPerChar = ini_get('session.hash_bits_per_character');
    if (!$hashBitsPerChar) {
        $hashBitsPerChar = 5; // the default value
    }
    switch($hashBitsPerChar) {
        case 4: $pattern = '^[0-9a-f]*$'; break;
        case 5: $pattern = '^[0-9a-v]*$'; break;
        case 6: $pattern = '^[0-9a-zA-Z-,]*$'; break;
    }
    return preg_match('#'.$pattern.'#', $id);
}
```

The problem is that for some reason the session id is generated with  `hash_bits_per_character = 5` instead of `hash_bits_per_character = 4`. So, to solve this problem, all you need to do is force the `session.hash_bits_per_character` setting before calling `Zend_Session::start()` for the first time and Zend_Session will check the hash bits using the correct pattern:

```
Zend_Session::setOptions(['hash_bits_per_character' => 5]);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Only a little correction, it's `hash_bits_per_character` instead of `hash_bits_per_char` in set options. And you can set this on the application or in the `php.ini` file with `session.hash_bits_per_character = 5`. Thanks man!

Comment: @IgorBrites edited the answer with the correct option (that saved my day as well) :)